# How to access dictionaries of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indices

```
a=[{'1st innings': {'team': 'Islamabad United',
   'deliveries': [{0.1: {'non_striker': 'Sharjeel Khan',
      'bowler': 'Anwar Ali',
      'runs': {'extras': 0, 'total': 0, 'batsman': 0},
      'batsman': 'SR Watson'}},
    {0.2: {'non_striker': 'Sharjeel Khan',
      'bowler': 'Anwar Ali',
      'runs': {'extras': 0, 'total': 0, 'batsman': 0},
      'batsman': 'SR Watson'}},
    {0.3: {'non_striker': 'Sharjeel Khan',
      'bowler': 'Anwar Ali',
      'runs': {'extras': 0, 'total': 0, 'batsman': 0},
      'batsman': 'SR Watson'}},
    {0.4: {'non_striker': 'Sharjeel Khan',
      'bowler': 'Anwar Ali',
      'runs': {'extras': 0, 'total': 0, 'batsman': 0},
      'batsman': 'SR Watson'}},
    {0.5: {'non_striker': 'Sharjeel Khan',
      'bowler': 'Anwar Ali',
      'runs': {'extras': 0, 'total': 0, 'batsman': 0},
      'batsman': 'SR Watson'}},
    {0.6: {'non_striker': 'Sharjeel Khan',
      'bowler': 'Anwar Ali',
      'runs': {'extras': 0, 'total': 0, 'batsman': 0},
      'batsman': 'SR Watson'}}}]
```

How do i access different indices of this dictionary i.e '1st innings','batsman','total' etc in python

I keep getting the error **"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"** when i try to access 1st innings using **a["1st innings"]**

Comment: You have a list with a dict of dicts inside. Look for [.

Comment: try a[0]["1st innings"] <~ this should fix it

Comment: 'a' is a list, not a dictionary, so using `"1st innings"` (which is a key value) does not work, as the error message says.

Answer (score 0):

You have a - `list` of `dicts`. So you need to access like

```
print(a[0]['1st innings'])
```